# Straightedge and compass construction: focus of a parabola given $A,B,V$

Tags: euclidean-geometry, quadratics, conic-sections, geometric-construction

> $A,B,V$ are three distinct, non-collinear points in the plane and we want to find,
>   through straightedge and compass, the focus $F$ of a parabola $\wp$ with
>   vertex at $V$ and going through $A,B$.

Context: it is not difficult to prove that the solution is unique. We need five linear constraints to fix a projective conic: "$\wp$ is a parabola" is equivalent to "the center of $\wp$ lies on the line at infinity" and provides the first one; $A,B,V\in\wp$ provide the second, third and fourth constraints; "$V$ is the vertex of $\wp$" is equivalent to "the normal line at $V$ meets the line at infinity at $\wp$" and provides the fifth one.

Additionally, in some reference system centered at $V$ we have $A=(u,au^2), B=(v,av^2)$, hence if we manage to compute $|a|$ from the squared side lengths of $ABV$, namely 
$$u^2+a^2 u^4,\qquad v^2+a^2 v^4,\qquad (u-v)^2+a^2(u-v)^2(u+v)^2$$
we are done. On the other hand, it does not seem so trivial to do that by straightedge and compass.
[This page](http://users.math.uoc.gr/~pamfilos/eGallery/problems/ParaProblems.htm) collects a lot of facts on the Euclidean geometry of parabolas, that might be useful in tackling the current problem.

Comment: Note: the algebraic system of equations leads to a cubic, hence it might be *impossible* to solve this problem by straighedge and compass. In such a case, I am interested in a rigorous proof of this fact.

Comment: If you get a cubic, then it looks as if it would be easy to find situations in which that cubic has rational coefficients but it irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$. That would be enough to solve the problem (a nice problem, by the way).

Comment: Dorrie says that Newton solved how to pass a parabola through four points, based on auxiliary problem three points and axis direction are known.

Comment: @WillJagy: this sheds a peculiar light on the matter: in the $3$-points problem the direction of the axis has to be known, otherwise straightedge and compass are probably not powerful enough to solve the configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $AV=4, BV=5$ and $AB=6$ then $a^2$ turns out to be a root of the cubic polynomial
$$-28672-1229504 x-8266300 x^2+121550625 x^3$$
which is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{11}$, hence irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.
It follows that the given problem cannot be solved by straightedge and compass.